# How to display DataTable row in Repeater's footer

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I need to create table where all rows are inside `<tbody></tbody>` and last row (Total with sums of columns) is inside `<tfoot></tfoot>`.

Can I put last row of `DataTable` (which is bound to the `Repeater`) into the footer, where I can define appropriate template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to sum the columns via [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) of the Repeater.

For example(VB.NET, not tested, assuming there is a column named 'Total'):

```
Sub R1_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
     If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer) Then
        Dim tbl = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Repeater).DataSource, DataTable)
        Dim total = DirectCast(tbl.Compute("Sum(Total)", Nothing), Double)
        ' show this value in appropriate cell/control in footer '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I thought about something like this but I didn't know how to access DataTable from this event. I think it should work, but I didn't have time now to check, so I'll try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @Episodex: Edited my answer and corrected something obviously wrong. But you should have a clue now even if it's not 100% working.